# Main website in root folder / and other websites in subfolders /de /es

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, seo, base-url

We are trying for some weeks to setup Magento 2 with the following structure:

- **Main Shop**: example.com/
- **USA Shop**: example.com/**us**
- **UK Shop**: example.com/**uk**

I tried to set the following configuration:

`Stores -> Configuration -> Default -> Web -> Add Store Code to Urls`

It has a problem for us: it add the code to the Main Shop too. For SEO purposes, we want to have the Main Shop in the root.

How we can accomplish this? Thanks.